# Foreign Key constraints missing after phpmyadmin export

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys, key

I create a table in mysql using the following script:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_x_activities(
  id int NOT NULL auto_increment, 
  id_user int unsigned NOT NULL,
  id_attivita int unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES utente(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_attivita) REFERENCES attivita(id)
  ) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

When I export the created table from phpMyAdmin, I obtain the following script

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_x_activities` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_attivita` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_user` (`id_user`),
  KEY `id_attivita` (`id_attivita`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

So the question are: where is my foreign key constraints? does `KEY` refer to FK? Seems that the two tables `utente` and `attivita` are no longer referenced in the new generated script. where am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

In phpMyAdmin, configuring the export of the table I found the option "Display Foreign Key Relationship"
If I flag this option I otain also this code in the script

```
--
-- RELATIONS FOR TABLE `users_x_activity`:
--   `id_user`
--       `utente` -> `id`
--   `id_attivita`
--       `attivita` -> `id`
--

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `users_x_activity`
--
ALTER TABLE `users_x_activity`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `users_x_activities_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_user`) REFERENCES `utente` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `users_x_activities_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_attivita`) REFERENCES `attivita` (`id`);
```

This means that if I add the option "Display Foreign Key Relationship" I obtain also the FK constrains? in other case not?

Comment: Doesn't phpmyadmin add all table constraints AFTER the create table statements, as opposed to IN the create table statement? Did you check the end of your script for add constraint commands?

Comment: @BlaiseSwanwick I have edited my question. In the first generated script I have not obtain other statement. With the new option I have obtain other statement (see EDIT)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**So the question are: where is my foreign key constraints?**

They are defined in the database. The output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE users_x_activities` will include the foreign key constraint definitions.

The definitions of the foreign key constraints likely appear in separate ALTER TABLE statements at the end of the generated script.

**does KEY refer to FK?**

No. `KEY id_user (id_user)` here refers to an index.

**Seems that the two tables utente and attivita are no longer referenced in the new generated script.**

Yes, you are correct. The foreign key constraints are not included in the CREATE TABLE statement.

**where am I doing wrong?**

A MySQL `SHOW CREATE TABLE users_x_activities` will include the foreign key constraints.

The foreign key constraints are likely included in the script generated by phpMyAdmin, but at the end of the script, in separate `ALTER TABLE` statements.

Comment: Thank you @spencer. Using Display Foreign Key Relationship (as said in the EDIT) I obtain the statement that generate my foreign key constraints?

Comment: But if I export tables with foreign keys and data it fails on inserting data which are under the FK constraint. It happens if child table is filled before  parent table. But if I check without foreign key check in export i will get tables without FKs. How to solve it?

Comment: A couple of options. 1) load the tables in an order that doesn't violate the foreign keys. 2) if you know the rows don't violate any foreign key constraints, you can force MySQL to disable foreign key checking in the session. execute **`SET foreign_key_checks = 0`**, then run the insert statements, and when done, reenable foreign key checks by executing **`SET foreign_key_checks = 1`** (that essentially relieves MySQL from any responsibility for the data integrity; the session is responsible for guaranteeing integrity.

Comment: 3) or, drop the foreign keys, run the inserts, and then re-add the foreign keys. (re-adding the foreign keys on large tables can be expensive in terms elapsed time,and holding locks for the duration.)

Comment: What session do you mean? I am talkin about export file which has or has not FK definitions. Solution would be if FK definitions were after all table definitions and insertions. Can I set it in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Problem was on my side. I was creating FKs which refers to table which column had no index. I was altering existing database and index was missing on one old table. Now everithing works with "disalows FKs check" option in PhpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

There are two type of constraints when you managing your tables with phpmyadmin:

- internal: when you set constraints with phpmyadmin designer for example the constraints stored as internal,that will not be included in export.
- innoDB: these constraints included in export check out linked video about it

[Setting up a foreign key constraint](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A42FG4LzdbY)

Comment: Excellent video tutorial! But exists there a way to change db type from MyISAM to InnoDB? Default was MyISAM in myPhpAdmin ...

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps :

1. phpmyadmin configuration
   [image: phpmyadmin configuration]
2. export time customer configuration
   [image: export time customer configuration]

Comment: This answer would be better if it described the steps in text as well as images.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).